# Contract working on Javascript VM and not Web3 Provider, why?

Tags: contract-development, remix, contract-invocation, contract-debugging, payable

Here is the code:

Calling contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Caller {

    address public called_address;

    constructor() public payable {

    }

    function set_address(address _addy) public {
        called_address = address(_addy);
    }
    function () public payable{
        Called c = Called(called_address);
        if (c.get() > 10 ){
            revert("Too much sauce");
        }
        c.set();
    }

}

interface Called{

    function set() external;
    function get() external view returns (uint);
}
```

Called Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Called{

    uint public number;

    function myuint() public view returns(uint _number) {
        _number = number;
    }

    function set() public {
        number++;
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint){
        return number;
    }
}
```

When I call the fallback function I get an error. This only happens when using Web3 provider, but works well in JavaScript VM. Saw this question too [Can't call another contract constant function in Remix in Web3 provider mode, but it works in Javascript VM](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47245/cant-call-another-contract-constant-function-in-remix-in-web3-provider-mode-bu)

Is it a bug in Remix? Does my code have an error? Why do I get different results with the different environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current online version of remix (0.6.4) has some bugs related to intercontract communication which are present using external web3 provider or facility. Try to use current alpha version (http://remix-alpha.ethereum.org) and, if all is then ok, simply switch to it. The current alpha version shall be the current online version (as 0.7.0 version) in short.